# python 3: received 403:forbidden error when using request

Tags: python-3.x, url, request, wget

HTTP Error 403: Forbidden is generated by using the either one of the following two commands.

`requests.get('http://www.allareacodes.com')`

`urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.allareacodes.com')`

however, I am able to browse this website in chrome and check its source. Besides, `wget` in my cygwin is also capable of grabbing the html source.

anyone knows how to grab the source of this website by using packages in python alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have errors in your code for requests. It should be:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://www.allareacodes.com')
print(r.text)
```

In your case however, the website has a "noindex" file that stops scripts from getting the raw HTML data. As a solution, simply fake your headers so that the website thinks you're an actual user.

Example:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://www.allareacodes.com', headers={
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
})
print(r.text)
```

Comment: thanks very much! I will check the doc for the headers option.